# How would I calculate the error in LU Decomposition of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I am currently practicing the LU Decomposition of n x n matrices. After finding the LU decomposition, I am lost on how to find the error. 
I am trying to understand the notation in a problem that asks me to find the 
 "error ||LU−A||∞". 
To solve this problem, do I do something with the norm?

```
Is the square root of largest eigenvalue of Atranspose * A my error?
```

A general explanation rather than an actual answer to my problem should suffice. Thank you!

Comment: The matrix norm should be $\|A\|_\infty = \max_i\sum_j |a_{ij}|$.

Comment: So to solve this problem I am only supposed to find the norm using the largest eigenvalue. (And that will be my error?)

Comment: No, not the largest eigenvalue. That's not a matrix norm anyway.